# detach and attach IAM roles to EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-emr

I have an EMR cluster running. I deleted the roles that were attached to that EMR and recreated the roles. I was hoping everything will work as expected as role names did not change.

Now when i try to run any AWS command on it, i get an error saying `fatal error: An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListObjects operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.`

I assume there may be a way for me to tell EMR that roles were attached and detached but I do not see one.

Is there a fix for this without me recreating the EMR cluster?

P.S. AccessKeys were never generated on EMR.

Comment: Interesting! A role is converted into temporary credentials. It sounds like it is trying to use the old credentials, but they aren't valid anymore. If you DELETED the roles rather than merely detaching them, then this would definitely explain what is happening. Check whether there is a `~/.aws/credentials` file that might have the old credentials. It's unlikely, but the `aws` command is getting the credentials from _somewhere_. Might even be in Environment Variables (run `set` to check).

Comment: It is using old credentials but i assumed those will be temp credentials and will eventually get refreshed but they never did or may be i did not wait long enough for the refresh credential process to kick-in. There is no way to detach the roles from EMR. At least i did not see any from the console.